# Number of answers as tie breaker for top answerers in tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, top-users, score, tag-score

Totally not in my own interest, cough cough…

[Currently](http://web.archive.org/web/20180505185402/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft-commands/topusers) the top two users in the "minecraft-commands" tag on gamingSE of the last 30 days have the same score, but a different amount of answers that gave them that score. They are apparently sorted arbitrarily, since web.archive.org and an incognito tab show it differently than a regular tab:
[image]
Can the amount of answers please be used as a tie-breaker? Either more answers make the user appear at the top (because, you know, it's more) or at the bottom (because the average score of these answers is lower), but it should be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Since Stack Exchange sites advocate quality as being what distinguishes its Q&A from that of other platforms I think they should rank a user with the same score from fewer questions more highly if a tie breaker is needed.

Comment: And to discourage simply posting a meaningless answer to get on top.

Comment: @PaulParker hopefully a meaningless answer would attract at least one downvote to break the tie in the other direction.